# Cannot set g:ale_fixers in ALE config on vim

Tags: vimrc, plugin-ale, filetype-javascript, eslint, filetype-typescript

I'm trying to config ALE in my vim and can't config the fixers, them aren't showing on ALEInfo.

I'm setting the config for typescript files (with and without react) with prettier and eslint.

What i'm doing wrong?

#### .vimrc config

```
(...)

let g:ale_linters = {
\ 'typescript': ['eslint', 'tsserver', 'typecheck'],
\ 'typescriptreact': ['eslint', 'tsserver', 'typecheck'],
\}

let g:ale_fixers = {
\   'javascript': ['prettier', 'eslint'],
\   'typescript': ['prettier', 'eslint'],
\   'typescriptreact': ['prettier', 'eslint'],
\}

let g:ale_fix_on_save = 1

let g:ale_linters_explicit = 1

" Completion
let g:ale_completion_enabled = 1

let g:ale_javascript_prettier_use_local_config = 1

let g:ale_completion_tsserver_autoimport = 1

let g:airline#extensions#ale#enabled = 1

nmap <silent> <C-k> <Plug>(ale_previous_wrap)
nmap <silent> <C-j> <Plug>(ale_next_wrap)

(...)
```

#### :ALEInfo

```
Available Linters: ['eslint', 'standard', 'tslint', 'tsserver', 'typecheck', 'xo']
  Enabled Linters: ['eslint', 'tsserver', 'typecheck']
 Suggested Fixers: 
  'eslint' - Apply eslint --fix to a file.
  'prettier' - Apply prettier to a file.
  'remove_trailing_lines' - Remove all blank lines at the end of a file.
  'trim_whitespace' - Remove all trailing whitespace characters at the end of every line.
  'tslint' - Fix typescript files with tslint --fix.
  'xo' - Fix JavaScript/TypeScript files using xo --fix.
 Linter Variables:

let g:ale_typescript_tsserver_config_path = ''
let g:ale_typescript_tsserver_executable = 'tsserver'
let g:ale_typescript_tsserver_use_global = 0
 Global Variables:

let g:ale_cache_executable_check_failures = v:null
let g:ale_change_sign_column_color = 0
let g:ale_command_wrapper = ''
let g:ale_completion_delay = 100
let g:ale_completion_enabled = 1
let g:ale_completion_max_suggestions = 50
let g:ale_echo_cursor = 1
let g:ale_echo_msg_error_str = 'Error'
let g:ale_echo_msg_format = '%code: %%s'
let g:ale_echo_msg_info_str = 'Info'
let g:ale_echo_msg_warning_str = 'Warning'
let g:ale_enabled = 1
let g:ale_fix_on_save = 1
let g:ale_fixers = {'typescript': ['prettier', 'eslint'], 'typescriptreact': ['prettier', 'eslint'], 'javascript': ['prettier', 'eslint']}
let g:ale_history_enabled = 1
let g:ale_history_log_output = 1
let g:ale_keep_list_window_open = 0
let g:ale_lint_delay = 200
let g:ale_lint_on_enter = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_filetype_changed = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_insert_leave = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_save = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_text_changed = 'normal'
let g:ale_linter_aliases = {}
let g:ale_linters = {'typescriptreact': ['eslint', 'tsserver', 'typecheck'], 'typescript': ['eslint', 'tsserver', 'typecheck']}
let g:ale_linters_explicit = 1
let g:ale_list_vertical = 0
let g:ale_list_window_size = 10
let g:ale_loclist_msg_format = '%code: %%s'
let g:ale_lsp_root = {}
let g:ale_max_buffer_history_size = 20
let g:ale_max_signs = -1
let g:ale_maximum_file_size = v:null
let g:ale_open_list = 0
let g:ale_pattern_options = v:null
let g:ale_pattern_options_enabled = v:null
let g:ale_set_balloons = 0
let g:ale_set_highlights = 1
let g:ale_set_loclist = 1
let g:ale_set_quickfix = 0
let g:ale_set_signs = 1
let g:ale_sign_column_always = 0
let g:ale_sign_error = '>>'
let g:ale_sign_info = '--'
let g:ale_sign_offset = 1000000
let g:ale_sign_style_error = '>>'
let g:ale_sign_style_warning = '--'
let g:ale_sign_warning = '--'
let g:ale_sign_highlight_linenrs = 0
let g:ale_statusline_format = v:null
let g:ale_type_map = {}
let g:ale_use_global_executables = v:null
let g:ale_virtualtext_cursor = 0
let g:ale_warn_about_trailing_blank_lines = 1
let g:ale_warn_about_trailing_whitespace = 1
  Command History:

(executable check - success) /home/wallace/development/sherlock/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js
(finished - exit code 0) ['/bin/zsh', '-c', 'cd ''/home/wallace/development/sherlock'' && ''/home/wallace/development/sherlock/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js'' -f json --stdin --stdin-filename ''/home/wallace/development/sherlock/src/lib/algoliaapi/credentials.ts'' < ''/tmp/vJldJxi/1/credentials.ts''']

<<<OUTPUT STARTS>>>
[{"filePath":"/home/wallace/development/sherlock/src/lib/algoliaapi/credentials.ts","messages":[],"errorCount":0,"warningCount":0,"fixableErrorCount":0,"fixableWarningCount":0}]
<<<OUTPUT ENDS>>>

(executable check - success) /home/wallace/development/sherlock/node_modules/.bin/tsserver
(started) ['/bin/zsh', '-c', '''/home/wallace/development/sherlock/node_modules/.bin/tsserver''']
(executable check - failure) typecheck
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I see that the variable shows itself properly set; have you tried running ALEFix or using the fix -on-save feature ? I’m not sure fixers have ever really shown in the info. You might ask the plugin maintainers...